# How to fix this layout? Margin or padding?

Tags: html, css

How to fix [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeamj.png)?

The staring of "I have read and understand..." and the starting of "Applicant’s signature..." are not at the same pacing. One is in `<p>` and one is a table in `<div>`. Here is my code of this part.

```html
<p style="margin:0;"><b>I have read and understand the “Personal Information Collection Statement” attached in this form.</b></p>
<p style="margin:0; height:6px;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin:0;">Please confirm that your instructions have been clearly, accurately, and completely set out in this form
before signing it.</p>
<p style="margin:0;">&nbsp;</p>

<div style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
 <table style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
 <tr><td style="width:60%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding:12px 12px 0px 0px; margin:0px;">
  <label><strong>Applicant’s signature: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td>
<td style="width:40%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding:12px 12px 0px 12px; margin:0px;">
  <label><strong>Date: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="width:60%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding:13px 12px 0px 0px; margin:0px;">
  <label><strong>Applicant’s name: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td>
<td style="width:50%;">
</td></tr>

 </table>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0px;">&nbsp;</p><p style="margin:0; paddihttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#ng:0px;">&nbsp;</p><p style="margin:0; padding:0px;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

---

After using the "cellspace=0" method, it is much better. But there is still a small space between them. This is the [other application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2LH9.png) I in a similar way. (I use this example because it can show the different much more easier. The one used above is harder to see the problem.)

Code for this part:

```html
<h2 style="font-size:140%; margin:0;"><strong>Your Registration Information</strong></h2>
<p style="margin:0; height:15px;">&nbsp;</p>
<div style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
 <table style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;" cellspacing="0">
 <tr><td style="width:50%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; ">
  <label><strong>Name: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td>
<td style="width:50%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;  margin-left:10px; ">
  <label><strong>Email: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="width:50%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding:13px 0px 13px 0px;">
  <label><strong>Phone: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td>
<td style="width:50%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;  margin-left:10px; padding:13px 0px 13px 0px;">
  <label><strong>Reference number: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="width:400px;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding: 0px 0px 2px 0px;">
  <label><strong>Date of submission: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td><td></td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: give cell spacing for the table as 0.
<table style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;" cellspacing="0">

Comment: you can give a `margin-left: -1px` for div inside the td.

Comment: problem still cannot be solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added  margin-left: -1px; in the required div.

```html
<h2 style="font-size:140%; margin:0;"><strong>Your Registration Information</strong></h2>
<p style="margin:0; height:15px;">&nbsp;</p>
<div style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
 <table style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;" cellspacing="0">
 <tr><td style="width:50%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;  margin-left: -1px;">
  <label><strong>Name: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td>
<td style="width:50%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;  margin-left:10px; ">
  <label><strong>Email: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="width:50%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding:13px 0px 13px 0px; margin-left: -1px;">
  <label><strong>Phone: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td>
<td style="width:50%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;  margin-left:10px; padding:13px 0px 13px 0px;">
  <label><strong>Reference number: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="width:400px;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding: 0px 0px 2px 0px;  margin-left: -1px;">
  <label><strong>Date of submission: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td><td></td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you are talking about the td property. My bad. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set cellspacing attribute for the table to 0.

```html
<p style="margin:0;"><b>I have read and understand the “Personal Information Collection Statement” attached in this form.</b></p>
<p style="margin:0; height:6px;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin:0;">Please confirm that your instructions have been clearly, accurately, and completely set out in this form
before signing it.</p>
<p style="margin:0;">&nbsp;</p>

<div style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
 <table style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;" cellspacing="0">
 <tr><td style="width:60%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding:12px 12px 0px 0px; margin:0px;">
  <label><strong>Applicant’s signature: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td>
<td style="width:40%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding:12px 12px 0px 12px; margin:0px;">
  <label><strong>Date: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="width:60%;">
 <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding:13px 12px 0px 0px; margin:0px;">
  <label><strong>Applicant’s name: </strong></label>
  <span style="flex: 1; display: block;">
  <input style="width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;"/>
  </span>
 </div>
</td>
<td style="width:50%;">
</td></tr>

 </table>
<p style="margin:0; padding:0px;">&nbsp;</p><p style="margin:0; paddihttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#ng:0px;">&nbsp;</p><p style="margin:0; padding:0px;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I still have a bit problem with that. I edited my original post above. Thank you.

Comment: I just want to ask, why do I need to such "margin-left: -1px;"? Is there any problem in my original code?

Answer (score 0):

padding is for the parent..
margin is for the child. so either of the 2 you can use for the positioning.
or you can set `position:relative` to an object and set its position (left,top,right,bottom
)